# What does changing ODES in simulink mean

Tags: simulink, ode

I have implemented two controllers in simulink; PID and fuzzy controller. odes for implementation of both controllers are different. PID is implemented in ode45 while fuzzy controller is implemented in ode14x. This is done to achieve the desired response i.e convergence to reference value. But still I am unable to understand what does changing ode mean....I know there are different methods of solving odes but exactly what I am doing when I am changing ode in simulink.... guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ODEs are solvers. Simulink computes everything step by step, so ODEs define the length of the step (nest point will be 0.0001 secs later or 0.5 later?) adn also made the calculus of the numerical derivatives.

For example ODE1 is Euler. Derivatives are the simplest ones : `dF(n)=(F(n)-F(n-1))/At`   and `At` (step of time) is always a constant defined by the user.

Of course ODEs are not always perfect nor always work in all cases, that's why Matlab has so many of them. and yes, several times you PID will work in a ODE but not in other.

The Nightmare of Simulink debugging is change your model for days until you realised it was the ODE.... So many hours wasted...

Answer (score 0):

A moderately detailed description/comparison of the solvers can be found at

http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/choosing-a-solver.html

Comment: I have already seen it but my question is why PID controller don't work in ode14x and fuzzy in ode45. Why I don't get the same response in every ode. Fuzzy works only in ode14x while pid in ode45.

Comment: When you choose a solver you are simply telling Simulink which mathematical algorithm to us to integrate the dynamics of your model through time.  Different solvers are designed to work better in different modelling situations.  If they gave the same result then by definition there would only need to be one solver (i.e. there wouldn't need to be a number of them to choose from).  Some are faster, some work better for stiff systems, they all have different convergence characteristics.